# Tmux copy and scroll iterm

Tags: tmux, macos, iterm

How can I copy from a large file by scrolling.
I am unable to start the selection.
I was able to start copy mode by

```
ctrl + B [
```

But I am unable to begin the selection . I used `space`  still no luck.I have the below output for tmux list-keys after grepping selection from it

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-Space              send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-g                  send-keys -X clear-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-w                  send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDrag1Pane       select-pane \; send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDragEnd1Pane    send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-w                  send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi C-j                  send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi Enter                send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi Escape               send-keys -X clear-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi Space                send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi A                    send-keys -X append-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi MouseDrag1Pane       select-pane \; send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane    send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

> NB : I dont have a tmux conf at ~/.tmux_conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you might be in is "copy-mode" instead of "copy-mode-vi". Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as shown in the first line of command `tmux list-keys`:

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-Space              send-keys -X begin-selection
```

If that works, you'll need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> for copying it into the buffer as shown:

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-w                  send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: it worked but what is M-w ? I is that mouse and w ?

Comment: @GabrialJohnas The `M` represents the `alt` key.